# Text String Processing from Inline JS

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I have the following code that is pulling from inline JS on a webpage to pull the webID. This is being used for a Chrome extension that will display just the site's webID when clicked:

```
// payload.js script --> insert into the current tab after the popout has loaded
window.addEventListener('load', function (evt) {
    chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
        file: 'payload.js'
    });;
});

//popout.html
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message) {
    document.getElementById('body').innerHTML = message;
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    code: '(' + (() => {

    for (var el of document.querySelectorAll('script[if="inlineJs"]')) 

    {
      var m = el.textContent.match(/"([^"]*webId*[^"]*)"/);
      var webid = m     
        if (webid) return webid[1];
        else {return document.getElementById('body').innerHTML = "This is not a CDK site";}     
    }
  }) + ')()',

  }, results => {
  if (!chrome.runtime.lastError && results) {
    document.getElementById('body').textContent = decodeURI(results[0]);
  }
}); 

});
```

Currently this returns the following:

```
{"cache":{"Co.context.configCtx":{"webId":"gmps-salvadore","locale":"en_US","version":"LIVE","page":"HomePage","secureSiteId":"b382ca78958d10048eda00145edef68b"},"features":{"directivePerfSwitch":true,"enable.directive.localisation":true,"enable.directive.thumbnailGallery":true,"enable.new.newstaticmap":false,"disable.forms.webId":false,"use.hydra.popup.title.override.via.url":true,"enable.directive.geoloc.enableHighAccuracy":true,"use.hydra.theme.service":true,"disable.ajax.options.contentType":false,"dealerLocator.map.use.markerClustering":true,"hydra.open.login.popup.on.cs.click":false,"hydra.consumerlogin.use.secure.cookie":true,"use.hydra.directive.vertical.thumbnailGallery.onpopup":true,"hydra.encrypt.data.to.login.service":true,"disable.dealerlocator.fix.loading":false,"use.hydra.date.formatting":true,"use.hydra.optimized.style.directive.updates":false,"hydra.click.pmp.button.on.myaccount.page":true,"use.hydra.fix.invalid.combination.of.filters":true,"disable.vsr.view.from.preference":false}},"store":{"properties":{"routePrefix":"/hydra-graph"}}}
```

I would like it to just return the 'gmps-salvadore'. This would be used on multiple sites and the webID will change from site to site with differing prefixes from "lex" to "motp". Is it possible to have the extension only pull the webID from various sites?

Comment: Use [JSON.parse()](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp) to fetch the specific property you want.

Comment: I tried this originally but I just keeping "null"

//popout.html
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message) {
 document.getElementById('body').innerHTML = message;
 chrome.tabs.executeScript({
  code: '(' + (() => {
   for (var el of document.querySelectorAll('script[if="inlineJs"]')) {
    var m = el.textContent.match(/"([^"]*webId*[^"]*)"/);
    var obj = JSON.parse(m);
    var myVar = obj.cache["Co.context.configCtx"].webId;
    window.alert("webId is " + myVar);
    return myVar;
   }
  }) + ')()',
 },